# How to have the same updated value of a Parent class be passed down to a inner class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to access the value of an attribute defined at the parent class inside an inner class, here's the code:

```py
class main(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.session_id = None
        self.devices = self.Devices(self.session_id)

    class Devices(object):
        def __init__(self, session_id):
            self.session_id = session_id
```

And here's how I would like to use it:

```
>>> m = main()
>>> m.session_id = 1
>>> m.session_id
1
>>> m.devices.session_id
>>>
```

My expectation is that `m.devices.session_id` will always have the exact same value as `m.session_id`. I understand that at this point when I instantiate the inner class the session_id value is passed down as None because that's how it was initiated but I'm not sure how I can keep both values the same without doing something very ugly like:

```
m.devices.session_id = m.session_id
```

outside the class code.

How can I accomplish that inside the class itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer works, but I think this is a better design: lose the nested class, and add a getter on the device object to lookup a backref:

```
class Main(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.session_id = None
        self.devices = Devices(main_obj=self)


class Devices(object):
    def __init__(self, main_obj):
        self.main_obj = main_obj
        ...

    @property
    def session_id(self):
        return self.main_obj.session_id
```

The difference here is that you're not storing the same data twice, so they can not get out of sync - there is only one "source of truth" for the `session_id` (on main object).

In the earlier answer, the data is actually stored in two different namespaces and will get out of sync as easily as `m.devices.session_id = 123`.

Comment: Agreed, while the initial response solved my case I was looking more for something that is a reference to the same object across both classes. This design accomplishes that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
class main(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._session_id = None
        self.devices = self.Devices(self._session_id)

    @property
    def session_id(self):
        return self._session_id

    @session_id.setter
    def session_id(self, value):
        self._session_id = self.devices.session_id = value

    class Devices(object):
        def __init__(self, session_id):
            self.session_id = session_id
```